# How do I use no-boil lasagna noodles in a normal recipe?

Tags: substitutions, lasagna

How do I convert a normal lasagna recipe to use no-boil noodles?  Do I need to add extra liquid or just make sure that the dish is covered really well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'no-boil' pasta straight from the box, alternatively, you can soak it it warm water for a few minutes. The soaked pasta may prove to be a little easier to manipulate when building the lasagne. However, providing there is enough liquid in the sauce, soaking is unnecessary.

Personally, I'd cover the dish with foil until the last 10 to 15 minutes of the cooking process, this will allow the pasta to cook and it should prevent the sauce from drying out. The last 10 to 15 minutes uncovered will provide the colour.

Comment: Many lasagna recipes will cook raw noodles sufficiently. Experimentation will be necessary to determine if the resulting lasagna is too dry. A quick soak will alleviate some of the dryness.

Answer (score 1):

I have had great success just simply substituting out the traditional and in with the no-boil, without any modification to the recipe.  Usually I end up letting the dish sit for a while (5 minutes or so), and the liquid ends up starting to soak in at that point.